# Simulate external webservice for integration test

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing

I have to simulate external webservice, specially SOAP webservice, to run integration test in java.

Any suggestion?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" is not a question.

Comment: Write a soap service demonstrating the behavior you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches to this:

1. Run your integrations tests against the *real* external webservice, or a test version of it.
2. Write your own test webservice that simulates the subset of the external service's behavior required for your integration tests.

Note that depending on the nature of the service you are trying to simulate, your test service could be pretty dumb; e.g. providing pre-computed / hard-wired responses to expected requests.

---

There is no magic here.  Just common sense and hard work.

Comment: There are any framework or library to help for buld the simulated test, can you raccomand me?

Comment: 1) None that I am aware of.  2) Requests for recommendations are off-topic.